# UISearchBar Bookmarks

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar, bookmarks

Does anyone have a good sample of storing bookmarks for a UISearchBar? What's the most elegant way to store this? Any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableArray. Whenever user searches for something add the string object to the array. If you want to show the list of bookmarks, have a tableview just below the searchbar with the list of bookmarks matches keyword. If any bookmarks matches the keyword make the tableview visible otherwise hide. If you want to save the bookmarks locally to persist across application launches, you can use [array writeToFile:@"filename"]; and you can retrieve by [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:"filename"];